# Sending PDF File with PHP Email

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use the following code to try and send a PHP Email with a PDF attachment.

I get the message 'Mail Sent. Thank You'. However, No email is being sent.

Please could someone show me / explain to me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "example@example.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $subject = "Subject Here";
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $file = $_POST['upload'];
   
    
    $headers = 'From: someone@gmail.com ' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: someone@gmail.com   ' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $file, $email, $headers);
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Form submission</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="file" name="upload" accept="application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-excel" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: Though, from a quick glance, `someone@someone@gmail.com` is not a valid e-mail.

Comment: @El_Vanja not really i don't want to use PHP mailer function if i can help it.  The code works fine if i take out the file attachment code

Comment: That linked question has 21 (*twenty one*!) subtitles describing potential failures, 20 of which concern PHP and its `mail` function directly. How did you draw the conclusion that the solution is using PHPMailer?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues with your code, and it is recommended to first check the syntax and documentation on official site. For instance your are passing $file as parameter to mail function, but there is no FILE parameter in mail function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Then you are not saving the uploaded PDF to any disk to send from. Uploaded files are captured through `$_FILES` variable not `$_POST` variable. You need to see that too.

Then sending any file is tricky job, and your job can be ease by using some library function such as `PHPMailer` so try to refer those.